# Should I use beer gas to dispense carbonated kegs?

Tags: keg

Suppose I have a keg of carbonated beer and a kegerator. Can I hook the keg up to beer gas (nitrogen, CO2 mix)? Would this affect the beer in any way, or would I have to carbonate with the beer gas to get any advantage to pushing with beer gas? Would I need a stout faucet? Longer lines to balance the system?

Answer (score 2):

What you propose is the usual way it's done.  Carbonate with CO2 (that's why it's called carbonation!), then dispense with beer gas.  You do not need a stout faucet.  You will probably need to lengthen your dispense lines.